# Parsing Edimax Smart Plug SP-2101W V2 XML Output

Tags: xml, perl

I am trying to access the smartplug.cgi of Edimax's smart plug SP-2101W V2 to work with the values of current and power. Unfortunately the output is (like) XML and I'm not familiar with. 
The output of Edimax I get is just one line:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF8"?><SMARTPLUG id="edimax"><CMD id="get"><NOW_POWER><Device.System.Power.NowCurrent>0.7988</Device.System.Power.NowCurrent><Device.System.Power.NowPower>152.06</Device.System.Power.NowPower></NOW_POWER></CMD></SMARTPLUG>
```

All I want to have is an output like:

> Current: 0.7988A
>
> Power: 152.06W

At the end of the day, I ask for some support to code the parser with `XML::LibXML` after loading the xml content.

My dirty perl code so far:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl


#
# curl --digest -s -X POST -d '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF8"?><SMARTPLUG id="edimax"><CMD id="get"><NOW_POWER><Device.System.Power.NowCurrent></Device.System.Power.NowCurrent><Device.System.Power.NowPower></Device.System.Power.NowPower></NOW_POWER></CMD></SMARTPLUG>' http://admin:XXXXXXXX@10.100.100.46:10000/smartplug.cgi
#

use strict;
use warnings;
use Capture::Tiny ':all';
use XML::LibXML;

my ($ip, $password) = @ARGV;
my $username = "admin";
my $command_get_power = "curl --digest -s -X POST -d '<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF8\"?><SMARTPLUG id=\"edimax\"><CMD id=\"get\"><NOW_POWER><Device.System.Power.NowCurrent></Device.System.Power.NowCurrent><Device.System.Power.NowPower></Device.System.Power.NowPower></NOW_POWER></CMD></SMARTPLUG>'";

my $url = " http://admin:" . $password . "@" . $ip . ":10000/smartplug.cgi";
my $exec_cmd = $command_get_power . $url;


my ($stdout, $stderr, $exit) = capture {
        system($exec_cmd);
};

print $stdout;

my $xml_data = XML::LibXML->load_xml(string=>$stdout);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
use XML::LibXML qw();
my $xml = '<?xml vers…………';
my $dom = XML::LibXML->load_xml(
    string => \$xml
);
print $dom->findvalue('//Device.System.Power.NowCurrent'); # 0.7988
print $dom->findvalue('//Device.System.Power.NowPower');   # 152.06
```